# Can I apply for a working holiday visa at age 30 and get the full 12 months?

Tags: visas, australia, working-holiday

I am British and approaching 30 years old and would like to apply for a Working Holiday (subclass 417) visa in Australia. **If I successfully apply and enter the country already age 30 and a bit am I still able to enjoy the full twelve months duration or does the visa expire as I turn 31 a few months later?** From what I can gather from the immigration pages the twelve month duration is universal as long as I am within the age limit upon arrival but I would like to check this understanding before applying.

Although Australia is the main place I am considering, I would also be interested to know whether the answer to this question is more broadly applicable.

Comment: You need to enter the country before you turn 31. Once you do you are allowed to stay for 12 months.

Answer (score 5):

Posters on https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g255055-i120-k11842973-30_31_year_old_working_holiday_visa_417_query-Australia.html and https://www.outback-australia-travel-secrets.com/work-visa-for-30-year-old.html report having received 12 month visas at the age of 30

Comment: Perfect - this is precisely the clarificaion I was looking for.

Comment: AFAIK the same holds true for the working holiday program in Canada. Your age has to be between 18 and 30 (inclusive) i.e. you are an adult and not yet 31 both when you apply AND when the request is processed. When your visa is approved, it is always for the full 12 months of the working holiday program. (12 for most other nationalities, IIRC 24 for British and Irish) You have to enter the country within 12 months of the issue date of the visa. The date of first entry after the visa is awarded starts the clock on the  12/24 month validity period.